# Finding data in mongodb by column name without a known _id

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to select `id` and `property_name` just like i would on mysql

`select property_name,_id from properties from properties`

In mongodb that is

```
> db.properties.find({
...
... },{
...    "property_name": 1
... }
... );
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6098e4743569ea6d9d6985b2"), "property_name" : "Aero Club" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6098f8e7a3397059ef264932"), "property_name" : "Radisson Blu Hotel" }
>
```

This is my php code

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->hotel->properties;

//echo $collection->count();


echo "<pre>";   
print_r($collection->find(array(), array("property_name" => 1))).iterator_to_array();
echo "</pre>";
```

I don't see the array of id and property_name returned anywhere so its hard fro me to loop through the returned object.

After returning the id and property, i wan't to translate this query into mongodb

```
select * from rooms where (has_sauna = 'yes' OR has_elevator = 'yes' or has_television = 'yes') and (price between "200" and "300" )
```

How can i fix the php query?.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
$collection->find(
    { $and: [
        { $or: [
            {has_sauna : 'yes'},
            {has_elevator : 'yes'},
            {has_television : 'yes'}
        ]},
        { price: {$gt : 200, $lt : 300} }
    ]}
);
```

Comment: I wanted to start with this `select property_name,_id from properties` then work up from there

Comment: Oh my mistake, i didn't perceive your full question.

Comment: I want to know how i can limit the number of columns i can retrieve.

Comment: How about add a nested mongo query once you get the _id and property_name.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the id and property name like this

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->hotel->properties;


$cursor = $collection->find();

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    echo '"_id": '.$document["_id"]."<br />";
    echo '"property name": '.$document["property_name"]."<br />";
}
```

While this works, i would like to know how to specify what columns/fields to find.